# Laravel array validation - finding the array key for error highlighting

Tags: jquery, laravel, validation, jquery.repeater

I have a repeating field which allows users to upload multiple files at once, using the https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater package.

I have a form request for validation, which works, but in the view I don't know how to highlight only the fields where errors are present. In the image below, only the first row contains an error, but both rows are highlighted.

[image]

In my form request I have the following:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ...
        'task_files.*.file_path' => 'required|max:10000',
        'task_files.*.title' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
        'task_files.*.file_description' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
        'task_files.*.file_type' => 'required|numeric',
    ];
}
```

In my view I have:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('task_files.*.file_path') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
    {{ Form::file('file_path', ['class' => 'file_input'])}}
    @if ($errors->has('task_files.*.file_path'))
        <div class="form-control-feedback">
            {{ $errors->first('task_files.*.file_path') }}
        </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

Having a look at the ViewErrorBag class, I see that the key of the failing field is present, but how can I incorporate this into my view?

```
"task_files.0.file_description" => array:1 [▼
  0 => "The file description is required"
]
```

**Edit:** When validation fails the fields are not created by a loop in the Blade template. I am using `$repeater.setList()` to set the data using the Laravel `old()` helper function.

Comment: Are you using `looping` for the inputs? Also, what laravel version you're using?

Comment: L5.5. I am using $repeater.setList() to set the list of fields when validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking if

```
$errors->has('task_files.*.file_path')
```

in your template with every **file** input you render, do a similar check but use the file input's index instead of the asterisk:

```
$errors->has('task_files.0.file_path') //for first file input
$errors->has('task_files.1.file_path') //for second file input
```

Comment: Yes, that will work. The problem is that I'm setting the repeating fields from the old data with the $repeater.setList() method when the request fails, because I don't know how many fields there will be in advance. So I can't check the loop index in the Blade template. I think I need to pass the error data over to jQuery and somehow remove the error class where it isn't needed.